# Using .html with and MVC 4 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller I made called `test` and going to `website.com/test` works just fine. How can I make that same controller respond if I try to go to `website.com/test.html`?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2013/08/29/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AttributeRouting for example can do that

Example :

```
 [GET("test")]
 [GET("test.html")]
 public ActionResult test()
 {
     return view();
 }
```

http://attributerouting.net/

Answer (score 1):

`RouteConfig.cs` is the place to look at.

Solution 1: `IgnoreRoute`

In your `RouteConfig.cs`, under `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)`:

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("*.html");
```

Please make sure your `IgnoreRoute` statement is place ahead of all other `MapRoute` statement.

Solution 2: `MapRoute`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HtmlUrl",
    url: "{action}.html",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home"}
);
```